# Can I have an excel formula post output multiple results?

Tags: excel-formula

I have an interesting question. I am close with my current formula but am not sure if there is a better way to do this.

I have data from a PDF that I am importing into excel and it is pretty messy. It is a large compilation of different filings that include the name, address, county, etc.

When exported to excel the cells are merged in odd ways that make it hard to reference other cells.

Essentially I am wondering if there is a way for my formula to output the name, address, and county, each time it finds "Debtor Name" on the spreadsheet.

[image: picture of the spreadsheet]

You can't tell from the photo but the cells are all merged and it makes referencing them difficult.
[image: unmerged cells]

My current formula is =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Z$1,A7)),A8," ")

$Z$1 = "Debtor Name"

A7 = "Debtor Name" (From the cell information)

A8 = "name"

If true it outputs the "name" into my table I am creating. This is where it would be perfect to output the Debtor Type, Address, and County!

If false I output a space (so I can run this formula all the way down the 400 cells where Debtor Name appears in the A column. I later then turn the spaces into blanks, and remove them.

Any help would be appreciated and I will provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` to add multiple cell values to your output.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Z$1,A7)),A8&B8," ")
# or
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Z$1,A7)),A8&" "&B8," ")
```

First example just concatenates the values from cells A8 and B8.
Second example adds some text between the cell values. In this case I specified a space, but you could use a comma, underscore, entire phrases, etc.

Comment: Let me try that out. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Can I add a cell in between multiple values?

Comment: How do you mean? You want the outputs in multiple cells? AFAIK, best way to do that is create formulas in adjacent cells. Could use similar logic or just confirm the previous cell is not just a space.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do name in one cell, address in one cell, county in one cell. I could do similiar logic however these PDF's are not formatted the same in each instance. One time the debtor type starts in cell D, one time it starts in cell F. How could I confirm previous cell is not a space?

Comment: Let's say your previous output is in C8. `=IF(C8=" ", "is space", "not space")`. To address more of the formatting issues, I would need an example spreadsheet.

Comment: Can I attach a example to comments? Not sure how. Or just edit the post above? Probably a better idea........ However. This is almost working perfect, but my output is now: Business NameOrganization1234 Road North12345Out of State. I am unable to filter anything this way because none of the information is split into different columns.

Comment: You can edit by adding a section to the end of your existing question. Then I can update the answer as appropriate.